# PHP getting result from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am new to PHP I am trying to get the `foreach` loop looping result. 
The loop I have

```
foreach($results as $result){
   $result = $result['names'];
}
```

Inside the loop are `strings (John, Fred, Ann)`;

I am trying to get this outside the loop, when I try to echo $result I only have John, what should I do to get all three names?

I have tried to create an array like

```
$resultData= array();
foreach($results as $result){
  $resultData = $result['names'];
}
echo $resultData;
```

This doesn't work, does anyone have any suggestions?

Updated question:
When I try to `var_dump($resultData)` I am getting

```
string(7) "John" string(7)"Fred" string(7)"Ann"
```

Comment: have you tried `array_push()`?

Comment: you should consult the manual more in this topic, this is just simple array usage

Comment: Can you try Explode In For each Loop ?

Comment: Thank you for all your replies, this loop is an multidimensional array, I am trying to get a single loop result out, so I don't think explode the loop is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example too:

```
$employeeAges;
$employeeAges["Lisa"] = "28";
$employeeAges["Martin"] = "16";
$employeeAges["Erik"] = "35";
$employeeAges["Victor"] = "46";
$employeeAges["Grace"] = "34";

foreach( $employeeAges as $key => $value){
    echo "Name: $key, Age: $value <br />";
}
```

> Output
>   Name: Lisa, Age: 28 
>   Name: Martin, Age: 16 
>   Name: Erik, Age: 35 
>   Name: Victor, Age: 46 
>   Name: Grace, Age: 34

you can do it like this too:

**foreach syntax: **$something** as **$key** => **$value** 
 For each element of the $employeeAges associative array I want to refer to the key as **$key** and the value as **$value**.

```
$employeeAges;
$employeeAges["Lisa"] = "28";
$employeeAges["Martin"] = "16";
$employeeAges["Erik"] = "35";
$employeeAges["Victor"] = "46";
$employeeAges["Grace"] = "34";

foreach( $employeeAges as $name => $age){
    echo "Name: $name, Age: $age <br />";
}
```

The operator "=>" represents the relationship between a key and value. You can imagine that the key points => to the value. In our example we named the key **$key** and the value **$value**. However, it might be easier to think of it as **$name** and **$age**. Below our example does this and notice how the output is identical because we only changed the variable names that refer to the keys and values.

You still get the same output.

> Output
>   Name: Lisa, Age: 28 
>   Name: Martin, Age: 16 
>   Name: Erik, Age: 35 
>   Name: Victor, Age: 46 
>   Name: Grace, Age: 34

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Comment: Let me know if you got any questions I may be able to help you =) 

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
foreach($results as $result){
$resultData[] = $result['your_value'];
}
print_r($resultData);
echo $resultData[0];
```

Comment: can you please update your question with the array you get by doing var_dump($results) ?

Comment: Yes you are right, I am trying to get this print_r  result. I tried $results = print_r($resultData, true);  but this returns nothing, what is the best way to get this result? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @user2983797 try this `var_dump($results)`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
 $resultData= array();`
 foreach($results as $key => $result){
      $resultData[$key] = $result['names'];
 }
  echo "<pre>", print_r($resultData, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper code. You have not declared the i properly

```
$resultData= array();
$i = 0;
foreach($results as $result){
      $resultData[$i] = $result['names'];
      $i++
}
//for single
echo $resultData[0];

//for whole
print_r($resultData);
```

Comment: just asking, why do you need to declare `$i`, if you use foreach anyway?

Comment: @GaLaBoOnZ , actually i relates the answer with the question. He used variable 'i', that why i told him the correct format of using $i. Nothing else. so many other ways are available but user should understand, what mistake he had done.

Comment: @MahaDev Oh ok, my bad just noticed that the post was edited and removed `$i` from the post. :P

Comment: @GaLaBoOnZ, whatever i got -1. :(

Comment: @MahaDev +1 for explanation :)

Comment: @GaLaBoOnZ Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use explode in foreach loop

```
 foreach($results as $result)
 {
      $result = explode(",",$result['names']);
 }
 print_r($result);
```

if you have a single name in $result then implode it with "," and explode it out side

```
     foreach($results as $result)
     {
          $val = implode(",",$result['names']);
     }
     $value = explode(","$val);
     print_r($value[0]);
```

Comment: if you have signle name in $result then use implode of it and explode it in out side

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got it working, this is the code. Thank you everyone.

```
      $results;         
      $results[0];
      $results[1];
      $results[2];
       $t = array();
        foreach($results as $key => $value)
        {        
          $t[]= $value['name'];
        }  
        $a = "'".implode("','", $t)."'";
        echo $a;
```